# Evernote API for business admin console

Tags: evernote

I want to check if there's any API for business admin console, so I can export notebooks from the admin perspective. I know the Evernote cloud API provide functions from the users perspective, can list business notebooks that had shared with you, while I want to backup all business notebooks by using admin privilege even if the notebook was not shared with me, any API assist this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to list all user-accessible notebooks regardless of whether it's shared with you or not by authenticating business. See [this page](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/business.php) for more details.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Even when you're authenticating to a business account, you're doing it by using OAuth to authenticate to a particular user account, and then accessing the business through that user account. You'll only have access to the portions of the business data which that user account has access to.

Comment: Well, like I wrote, it could give you the list of all "user-accessible" notebooks which I think is same as what you mentioned. It is bound to the permissions the OAuth user has. So, if the user account is a business admin, you should be able to access any business notebook in the business and I don't think there is any other "API for business admin".

Comment: Sorry, you're right, you did say "user-accessible" so that qualification makes sense. For the OP: try the `listAccessibleBusinessNotebooks` method.